# Hibernate with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mysql mode

Tags: mysql, hibernate

The following sql query (generated by Hibernate):

```
SELECT DISTINCT foreign_id FROM customer WHERE foreign_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY name
```

Returns this error message:

> Error Code: 3065. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'name' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

This is because the mysql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is set on the mysql server. We're not allowed to tinker with the sql modes.

Is there a way to tell Hibernate to include every necessary column in the select list? Is there another way to avoid this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and before finding the answer I first landed here. Just to help others I will post the link to the other forum where I found the answer.

How to avoid this error message ? [Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889899/disable-only-full-group-by-in-hibernate)

Thanks