# Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, group-by

I need to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in hibernate. 
This is my current session factory.
I am not sure how to specify the sql_mode='' in this.

```
<bean id="eAgilitySessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="eAgilitysDataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${mysql.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${dwh.db.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
         </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can set `sql_mode` in your JDBC connection string, e.g.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?sessionVariables=sql_mode=''
```

Comment: Works for me with MySQL v 5.17. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

for mysql 8.0

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?sessionVariables=&&sql-mode=''
```

Comment: why double ```&&```?

Comment: you have to use "sql_mode" instead of "sql-mode"

@BookOfZeus
[Check this answer]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62582767/7485707

Answer (score 0):

in local use : `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`