# How do I set SQL mode in the JDBC connection string for MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection-string, mysql-8.0

I recently upgraded my MySQL instance from 5.7 to 8.0.
I connected to my old instance using JDBC and a connection string that looked like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host:port]/[database]/?sessionVariables=sql_mode=''
```

After upgrading to 8.0 that results in this error

```
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the connection string near '='')'.
```

How do I set SQL mode in the JDBC connection string for MySQL 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in MySQL Connector/J. I have raised a bug report for it:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92485

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking I'm crazy, but it was just a goddamn bug. Just updated the connector and I worked. What a relief.

Answer (score 2):

> Try this for MySQL 8.0 in your JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host:port]/[database]/?sessionVariables=&&sql_mode=''
```

e.g.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?sessionVariables=&&sql_mode=''
```

> For MySQL 7.0 in your JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host:port]/[database]/?sessionVariables=sql_mode=''
```

e.g.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?sessionVariables=sql_mode=''
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with an old project and setting `sessionVariables=sql_mode=''` didn't work in my case. It was totally ignored.
Finally I found this [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23371) and its explanation:

> The driver needs the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode enabled to enforce JDBC compliance on truncation checks.
>
> If you can't use STRICT_TRANS_TABLES as part of your sql_mode, then you'll have to disable truncation checks by adding "jdbcCompliantTruncation=false" as a URL configuration parameter.

And indeed, setting `jdbcCompliantTruncation=false` worked for me.

Comment: [source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/bf6eb7be997d905a8d71a513bf9e6b3828a91ace/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L2222) you are right ,if `jdbcCompliantTruncation` not set to true ,it will overwrite to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES `

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because there's nothing in the sql_mode.

Comment: I tried with 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' and that did not work either.